# Проблемы с AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob

Поставил рекламу в приложение, но реклама не выводится.

Идентификатор в стринговом ресурсе есть

в OnCreate следующий код:

```
 // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());{

    }
```

Реклама должна вызываться по нажатию на кнопку, имеет следующий код:

```
         case R.id.progIm: // Нажатие на кнопку
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    //действие1
                }
            });

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            else{
                //действие1
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());{

                }
            }
        break;
```

Манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PlayGameActivity"> </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Идентификатор

```
<string name="ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
```

В логах при нажатие на кнопку дает какие-то ссылки. Рекламу так же не показывает следующее:

05-17 17:20:01.861 7614-7614/com.eddev.intellecualtechical W/Ads: JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
                                                                   (null:1)
05-17 17:20:01.861 7614-7614/com.eddev.intellecualtechical W/Web Console: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
                                                                           at null:1

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, не надо каждый раз заново грузить рекламу и сразу пытаться её показать пока она ещё гарантировано не загружена.

Т.е. сначала пытайтесь показать её и, если она не загружена, то только тогда загружайте её.